# easy_install broken on Mac

Tags: python, easy-install, osx-snow-leopard

I have copied my home folder from a Mac OSX 10.5 to a new Mac OSX 10.6. This broke east_intall for binary packages. For example if I use Python 2.5:

```
> easy_install celery
Searching for celery
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/
Reading http://github.com/ask/celery/
Reading http://celeryproject.org
Best match: celery 2.2.7
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/celery/celery-2.2.7.tar.gz#md5=5826cf891eaa6175cc7aab67818094fe
Processing celery-2.2.7.tar.gz
Running celery-2.2.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/TK/TKwwrl0JEyKrCVteN9D+Jk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-RSjVZt/celery-2.2.7/egg-dist-tmp-w4bMT_
...
In file included from Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.h:6,
                 from Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c:9:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5/Python.h:18:20: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
...
... millions of errors
...

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

If I use Python 2.6

```
> easy_install-2.6 celery
Searching for celery
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/celery/
Reading http://github.com/ask/celery/
Reading http://celeryproject.org
Best match: celery 2.2.7
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/celery/celery-2.2.7.tar.gz#md5=5826cf891eaa6175cc7aab67818094fe
Processing celery-2.2.7.tar.gz
Running celery-2.2.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/TK/TKwwrl0JEyKrCVteN9D+Jk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-dCVly4/celery-2.2.7/egg-dist-tmp-PqOUyI
error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: Setup script exited with error: /var/folders/TK/TKwwrl0JEyKrCVteN9D+Jk+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-dCVly4/celery-2.2.7/temp/easy_install-61UKvH/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-ExR4d0/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-OJw80Y/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-Zg0wGJ/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-aWn8hm/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-1TOXq2/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-r97tJG/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-CNdClq/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-XUejp4/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-xN6Jd6/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-zFbJOI/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-fc2q_2/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-1rTVrG/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-rii66v/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-cZBf5J/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-ICPv8M/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-RwRQIz/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-x74lHT/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-Yf8l74/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-fnl5Wt/Paste-1.7.5.1/temp/easy_install-OwWNt9/PasteDeploy-1.5.0/temp/easy_install-WkOs3d/Paste-1.7.5.1/docs/include/reference_header.txt: File name too long
```

This is not a celery specific question. I get similar errors with lxml, matplotlib, scipy, etc. The problem occurs with all binary packages, not pure python packages. What am I doing wrong?

```
> which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/easy_install
> which easy_install-2.6
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6
```

Comment: Which versions of easy_install are you using?  Please give the results of `which easy_install easy_install-2.6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell for sure with the abbreviated tracebacks you included.  One possibility is that the separate Python 2.5 you had installed on Mac OS X 10.5, most likely using a python.org installer, did not get copied over.  If so, you either need to install a similar Python 2.5 there or move `/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks` from the old installation.  Or you should update to using a newer Python, either a system one or one from python.org or one of the third-party open source distributors for Mac OS X, like MacPorts or homebrew or Fink or ActiveState.

Another possibility is that you need to install the optional `MacOSX 10.4u SDK` from the Xcode 3 installer for Mac OS X 10.6.  If that is the case, you should be seeing error messages that include either `10.3` or `10.4` in them.

Update: So it seems you do have an `easy_install` installed for the extra python.org or at least for whatever version of Python is pointed to by `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current`.  You seem to have to have two separate problems here (with the Python 2.5 and another with the system Python 2.6).  At this point, it is difficult for me to guess what either of the problems is without getting a lot more information.  It is probably best to clean up and start over.

1. If you want to remove the old Python 2.5 carried over from your old system, you can follow the instructions [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7107) on how to remove a python.org installed Python.  If you want to, you can make a copy of it first or rename it instead with something like:

   ```
   cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
   sudo mv 2.5 2.5-OLD
   ```

   Consider doing the same for any other Python version there.  DO NOT delete or modify any files in `/System/Library/Frameworks` or `/usr/bin`.  Those directories are part of OS X.
2. Make sure you clean up your shell profile files, `.bash_profile` etc, to ensure that your PATH no longer includes this Python.  Make you don't have any unexpected `PYTHONPATH` environment variables defined.
3. Make sure you don't have any outdated Distutils configurations files in your home directory.  Look for and rename or remove things like `.pydistutils.cfg`.

   ```
   cd ~
   ls -al
   ```

   Also make sure you don't have any unexpected private packages installed in local directories.

   ```
   ls -al ~/Library/Python
   ls -al ~/.local
   ```
4. Inspect and, if necessary, delete anything in the `site-packages` directories for the Apple-supplied Pythons:

   ```
   cd /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
   ls -al
   cd /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
   ls -al
   ```
5. Start a new terminal session and verify that all is well.
6. Decide what versions of Python you want to use with 10.6.  If you are OK with using the Apple-suppled 2.6.1 or 2.5.4 versions, then use them.  They both come with their own versions of `easy_install` in `/usr/bin`.

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
   -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  86000 Jun 24  2010 /usr/bin/python*
   -rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    925 Jul  7  2009 /usr/bin/python-config*
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/python2.5@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/python2.5-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/python2.6@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/python2.6-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
   -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  86000 Jun 24  2010 /usr/bin/pythonw*
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov  7  2010 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
   $ ls -l /usr/bin/easy*
   -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  925 Jun 30  2009 /usr/bin/easy_install*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  421 Jun 30  2009 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.5*
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  421 Jun 30  2009 /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6*
   ```
7. If you want more recent and up-to-date versions of Python, consider installing the latest Pythons (Python 2.7.2 is the current version of Python 2) from python.org or homebrew, MacPorts, Fink, ActiveState etc.  Update your shell PATH as necessary.  (For example, the python.org installers by default modify your shell profiles appropriately.)
8. If the installation doesn't already come with an `easy_install` (python.org doesn't, some of the others have an optional package to do so), install the [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) package which will provide an `easy_install` for it.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for any of the installed Python's but I did the following: 1) reinstalled xcode; 2) removed all installed Pythons; 3) installed 2.7. It now works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed XCode? It looks like you haven't.